# p:fileUpload and security

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3

I am having troubles getting the primefaces component to work in my secure glassfishv3 folder. The component works when it is in the "unsecured" area. Here is my web.xml setting for security

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Purchasing Administration: Requisition</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Requisition pages</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/processes/puradmin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>logged_in</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1464#c1

Its a known bug I guess.